# how to compare two text box and if both is empty how to print a message box in c#

Tags: c#

i am comparing here two text box and trying to print a error message if both are empty

```
         int ina=int.Parse(txttea.Text);
         int inb = int.Parse(txtcoffee.Text);
         int inc=0, ind=0;
         if(this.txttea.Text=="" && this.txtcoffee.Text=="")
          {
            MessageBox.Show("select a item");
            txttea.Focus();
          }
```

Comment: no what do you want?the title is different from written question!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `&&` you need `||` in the line:

```
if(this.txttea.Text=="" && this.txtcoffee.Text=="")
```

Note: The question does not correspond with the title of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how to validate the `TextBox` if is *empty* or *white space*.

The best way to deal withi this by using the [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you're in .Net 3.5 or later

```
 if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txttea.Text) || 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtcoffee.Text))
          {
            MessageBox.Show("select a item");
            txttea.Focus();
            return;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be the following below please edit your question to match the provided answer below

```
 int ina=int.Parse(txttea.Text);
 int inb = int.Parse(txtcoffee.Text);
 int inc=0, ind=0;
 if(this.txttea.Text=="" || this.txtcoffee.Text=="")
 {
     MessageBox.Show("select an item");
     txttea.Focus();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the empty string with `int.Parse` will give you an exception. I mean: `int.Parse("")` results in: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

To solve that problem, use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead:

```
int ina;
int inb;
if (int.TryParse(txttea.Text, out ina) && int.TryParse(txtcoffee.Text, out inb))
{
    //Ok, more code here
}
else
{
    //got a wrong format, MessageBox.Show or whatever goes here
}
```

You can also test them separately, of course [first ina then inb, or vice versa]:

```
int ina;
if (int.TryParse(txttea.Text, out ina))
{
    int inb;
    if (int.TryParse(txtcoffee.Text, out inb))
    {
        //Ok, more code here
    }
    else
    {
        //got a wrong format, MessageBox.Show or whatever goes here
    }
}
else
{
    //got a wrong format, MessageBox.Show or whatever goes here
}
```

Now, about comparing for the empty string, if you want the message when BOTH are empty:

```
if(this.txttea.Text == "" && this.txtcoffee.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("select a item");
    txttea.Focus();
}
```

On the other hand if you want the message when AT LEAST ONE is empty:

```
if(this.txttea.Text == "" || this.txtcoffee.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("select a item");
    txttea.Focus();
}
```